# Should Assertions be performed in BDD Given and When

Tags: cucumber, bdd

In Behavior Driven Development style of writing automated functional tests, it is generally understood that *Givens* should be the pre-condition that the system must be in, in order to begin the test, *When* should be the user action performed and *Then* should be asserting whether the observed matches the expected and fail or pass the test accordingly.

Off late my team has started performing assertions in Givens and Whens too which lead me to wonder if this is a correct practice.

For e.g -

```
Given a user with xyz privileges is logged in
When I click on the abc tab
Then records should be displayed
```

Should the *Given* in this test actually assert that the logged in user indeed has *xyz* privileges or assume the user has required privileges and just perform login

Also should the *When* assert that tab is visible before clicking?

Answer (score 3):

If "logging in" is a behaviour that's interesting* and you need examples to illustrate it** then it should be a "When", with the context in which it happens being the "Given", and the outcome that results being the "Then".

This is the case for any behaviour you need to illustrate with an example.

However, sometimes it can be useful to make assertions in a Given, just to check that the context really is set up properly. Sometimes when people start adopting BDD the environments can be a bit flaky, and it's handy to know if it's your scenario finding a bug that made it fail, or something earlier in the process. So for that reason, you might find assertions there.

The Given doesn't concern itself with *how* the system got into that state, though. If it has assertions, it should merely be to check that it *is*.

Another form I've seen is a check that the system is in the correct state for the context, with corrective action if it isn't.

Note that these are largely interim patterns. They can be helpful while teams are adopting BDD and getting their pipelines and automated deployments into shape.

Assertions which check the results of the "When" are part of the outcome, so part of the "Then". I can't imagine a case where you'd need to check the results of a "When" without it being an outcome. If you've got one, please give me an example.

[We discourage using clicking and UI details in scenarios.](https://dannorth.net/2011/01/31/whose-domain-is-it-anyway/) Work out what you're trying to achieve, and do that. Hide the clicking under the covers.

Most of the time automated scenarios aren't actually there to catch bugs; they're living documentation that helps people think about what they're trying to achieve and what the system already does, thus encouraging good design and preventing bugs in the first place.

I'd say something like "navigate to the ABC tab" and just do it; you'll get a relevant exception if it isn't there, and that won't happen as often as people reading the scenario will.

* It's logging in. It probably isn't.
** It's logging in. You probably don't.

Comment: Hi, thanx for the answer :) What happens if it is an assertion ot the test? ( E.g. `Given this dataset sample` (that I suspect my colegues will need to replace next year)', `When the dataset has salary information.` `And I compute the tax,` `Then the tax should be positive and less than the sallary`) Here I put an assert on `When` to test not the program but my test, ?

Comment: @ntg Thing about Givens is that it doesn't matter (from the scenario perspective) how you get them. Maybe you create them from scratch. Maybe they're part of the dataset. Maybe, if they don't exist, you create them; or maybe you look to see if they exist and throw an error if they don't. Both the last patterns I've used in the past and both are perfectly valid. Keep them within your "Given" steps; it's OK to call a "Then" assertion test from the Given as often outcomes of one scenario are the context for another. Refactor so that duplicated contexts or desired outcomes are clear and readable.

Comment: @ntg Just realized that my answer wasn't clear: unless you're interested in an example of setting up salary information, your dataset existing with salary information is part of a given, not a when. Computing the tax is the capability you're exercising so that's the "when" part; the state in which the "when" happens is all part of the Givens.

Answer (score 3):

Assertions in Givens and Whens are generally an indicator of immaturity of step definitions. So I might put one in a step that I am working on, but I wouldn't keep it there for very long.

I'd implement your step

`Given a user with xyz privileges is logged in`

as something like

```
'Given a user with xyz privileges is logged in' do
  user = create_user(privileges: xyz)
  login_as user: user
end
```

I would expect that the `create_user` method would be trusted pretty quickly and would not need an assertion. Same for the `login_as` method. (if methods like this aren't working properly you'd expect many scenarios to be broken)

Notice how this code makes it clear that there are two things going on and provides/uses an api that you would expect many other stepdefs to use. And how  any assertion you might want to keep really belongs in the helper methods not in the step def.

Answer (score 0):

There are no strict rules however in my experience I find it handy to define that there are no assertions there so it is clear what is actually tested and the test itself will run faster.

In the case if your abc tab is not displayed it shouldn't be clickable and then the test will fail either when identifying the object to click or when performing the next step(depends on the tools and method you use).

However you should make sure that the actual implementation of the test is not cheating and working with internals that are able to trigger a click even if the actual component isn't.

There is another point about the Given, there normally it is recommended to set up the environment for the test. This means you make sure that in your system there is a user and that user has been logged in. It makes no meaning to very that as you set it up, however if any failure occur you should fail fast to know what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Generally I would be careful about using assertions in the Given or When steps in the automation code.

However, I use login steps like this all over the place in my code as - when used correctly - can turn the step into a piece of context rather than an assertion itself.

For instance:

Is this user logged in?

- Yes => Do Nothing.
- No => Log out, then Log in as this user

In the example you gave, we know that we need the specific user to be logged in for this scenario to work, however we do not know if there is a different user logged in (other scenarios may have been run before it). If you use this step as a check to make sure that the correct user is logged in (as in my example), it is part of the context and it will speed up run time of the automation as you won't have to log in before and log out after every scenario.

Comment: For me an assertion that fails will make the test fail as well, so checking the exact same condition as an assertion to take an appropriate action would not be in fact an assertion.